# Gravity Form Checkbox Rendering on Mozilla

Tags: forms, css, gravity-forms-plugin

We have a form which shows rendering issues in Mozilla. We tried to increase the Checkbox Size and this is how a form renders in Mozilla: http://prntscr.com/jp6yv2 which is not correct. And, this is how a Form renders on Chrome http://prntscr.com/jp72h0 which is correct actually as you can see Checkbox Size Changes are showing up which are not taking effect in Mozilla. A Solution and thoughts on the issue are welcome.

Here is the code snippet which I am using

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px)
.ult-open ul.gfield_checkbox li.gchoice_1_3_1 input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 20px!important;
    height: 20px!important;
}
```

Comment: please add relevant code

Comment: @Taki Here is the CSS which I applied:@media screen and (min-width: 1200px)
.ult-open ul.gfield_checkbox li.gchoice_1_3_1 input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 20px!important;
    height: 20px!important;
}

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: @Sfili_81 thanks for that reference... that gave me a direction and I was able to fix the issue!

Comment: your welcome. @Sheryl